# How to create a column with the ranked index of the timestamp with conditions?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a challenging in R for which help would really be appreciated. I want to add a column to my dataset (100000+ rows) that represents the orders of the visitID's of a person based on time of the visit. The count should start at 1 from the most recent visit of a person and count upwards. To make it a bit more complex, the count should restart counting from 1 when a visit was a success.

Example with dummy data:

```
#Blockquote
person <- c("a","b","c","d","a","b","c","d","a","b")
visitId <- c(121,131,141,151,161,171,181,191,201,212)
timePM <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,11)
sucess <- c(0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0)
data <- data.table(person,visitId,timePM ,sucess)
```

The final result should output the following:

```
#Blockquote
person <- c("a","b","c","d","a","b","c","d","a","b")
visitId <- c(121,131,141,151,161,171,181,191,201,212)
timePM <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,11)
sucess <- c(0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0)
indexOrder <- c(2,3,2,2,1,2,1,1,1,1)
data <- data.table(person,visitId,timePM ,sucess,indexOrder)
```

I tried nested for loops but I didn't manage to solve the issue. I really hope someone can give me some tips.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: your final result is the same as your example

Comment: Apologies, you are absolutely right! The indexOrder should not be in the first blockquote. I created this column manually this time but it should be generated automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you are just trying to run a cumulative sum `sucess == 0` events by `person` and some chronological order. The only use case (I can think) of where a simple `cumsum` won't work is when the first visit was a success. So I just added this as a condition. So this seem to work

```
data[order(person, -timePM), # Sort by person and time (in decreasing order)
     indexOrder2 := cumsum(sucess == 0L | sucess[1L] == 1L), # cumsum with additional condition
     by = person] # Make sure we operate per person
data
#     person visitId timePM sucess indexOrder indexOrder2
#  1:      a     121      1      0          2           2
#  2:      b     131      2      0          3           3
#  3:      c     141      3      0          2           2
#  4:      d     151      4      0          2           2
#  5:      a     161      5      1          1           1
#  6:      b     171      6      0          2           2
#  7:      c     181      7      1          1           1
#  8:      d     191      8      0          1           1
#  9:      a     201     10      0          1           1
# 10:      b     212     11      0          1           1
```

Comment: yes it works indeed, great. Many thanks for your quick reply!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a *dplyr* version of David's answer:

```
library(dplyr)

person <- c("a","b","c","d","a","b","c","d","a","b")
visitId <- c(121,131,141,151,161,171,181,191,201,212)
timePM <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,11)
sucess <- c(0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0)
indexOrder <- c(2,3,2,2,1,2,1,1,1,1)
data <- data_frame(person,visitId,timePM ,sucess,indexOrder)

data %>%
    group_by(person) %>%
    arrange(person, -timePM) %>%
    mutate(IndexOrder2 = cumsum(sucess == 0L | sucess[1L] == 1L)) %>%
    arrange(timePM)
```